# R: convert data frame columns to least memory demanding data type without loss of information

Tags: r, memory-management

My data is massive and I was wondering if there is a way I could tell R to convert each column to data types which are less memory demanding without any loss of information.

In Stata, there is a function called `compress` that does that. I was wondering if there is something similar in R.

I would also be grateful if you have other simple advice of how to handle large datasets in R (in addition to using `data.table` instead of `dplyr`).

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and it's a little difficult to figure out how to respond without knowing more details. There are some tricks you can try to employ, such as turning categorical variables into factors, but I think the capability to compress data in R as a whole is limited

Comment: "Least memory demanding" has several caveats: if you are starting from strings, then reading it in will be a problem due to the global string hash in R; if there is a reading mechanism you can use (depending on your data-at-rest format) for reading it in numerically, that's the first place. Second, unfortunately, a float is a float is a float, it doesn't matter if it ends "exactly" in `.0000` or `.0001`, it's still the same number of bytes for storage, and since `Date`- and `POSIXt`-class objects are really `numeric` underneath, they are all affected by this.

Comment: Beyond that, other than something specific to _this_ dataset, there is no real way in R (that I know of) to compress data in-memory. Your better bet might be to work on smaller portions of the data at a time, using a database or some other data-at-rest storage that allows your "windows" of calculation/analysis.

Comment: There are tricks you can use with certain data types, but ultimately you are asking if there are ways within R to get it to make its memory allocation more efficient. If this was possible in the general case, the chances are very high that the R authors would already have built that in as standard.

Comment: Just to be certain, by *"data is massive"*, what reason do you have that this is a problem? What are the dimensions of your frame, and how much RAM do you have on the computer you're using?

Comment: I get messages saying I ran out of memory when trying to do operations in R (usually involving matching data.table objects). I have a data.table that is 800M rows long and has 3 columns - I can only load into R once my environment is empty. My computer has 16.0 GB of installed RAM. Thank you @r2evans

Comment: That's good information, thank you. Options as I see this: (1) Convert it to a `data.table` and learn its way of doing operations, it is much more memory efficient for most operations. (2) Read in and work on only small portions of the days at once. To help with both, I think we need to know more, likely as an [edit] to your question: why you think you cannot load a sub-dataset; how are you reading it in; what operations are you doing. If you need help trying `data.table`, we can help with that.